# Download Manager as server?

Tags: download, download-manager

I'm looking for a download manager that acts as a server. I'd like to have this download manager server running in the bacckgound. Maybe on another computer. The perfect solution would run on all major OS Mac, Linux, Windows with a nice graphical GUI if needed and a web interface.

An integration into the most used browsers would be nice as well.

Anyone knows such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a D-Link NAS. It has both a download client and a bitorrent client. Both accessible through a web interface. That way, you can offload downloading from your computer to the device and access the results later over the network.

Comment: That would be probably the easiest way. But instead of D-LINK I'll go for QNAP. But not at the moment because i have to put a few bucks aside first. So in the meantim I'm looking for an alternative. Maybe even an alternative taht will run on the QNAP/D-Link as well. ;)

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to download, several applications offer web UI and multi-platform apps. I.e., uTorrent runs on either PC or Mac OS and exposes a web interface and even an Android app to allow you to control downloads. Several other solutions offer the same.